# Getting URL From beginSheetModalForWindow:

Tags: cocoa, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, nsopenpanel

I'm using an OpenPanel to get a file path URL. This works:

```
[oPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
{
 NSURL *pathToFile = nil;

 if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
     pathToFile = [[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
}];
```

This doesn't, resulting in an 'assignment of read-only variable' error:

```
NSURL *pathToFile = nil;
[oPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
{
 if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
     pathToFile = [[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
}];
return pathToFile;
```

In general, any attempt to extract pathToFile from the context of oPanel has failed. This isn't such a big deal for small situations, but as my code grows, I'm forced to stuff everything -- XML parsing, core data, etc -- inside an inappropriate region. What can I do to extract pathToFile?

Thanks.

Comment: Just initialize you variable with __blocklike  "__block NSURL *pathToFile = nil"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This doesn't, resulting in an 'assignment of read-only variable' error:
>
> ```
> NSURL *pathToFile = nil;
> [oPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:theWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode)
> {
>  if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
>      pathToFile = [[oPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
> }];
> return pathToFile;
> ```

Yes, because you're trying to assign to the copy of the `pathToFile` variable that gets made when the block is created. You're not assigning to the original `pathToFile` variable that you declared outside the block.

You could use [the `__block` keyword](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) to let the block assign to this variable, but I don't think this will help because `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` doesn't block. (The documentation doesn't mention this, but there's no reason for the method to block, and you can verify with logging that it doesn't.) The message returns immediately, while the panel is still running.

So, you're trying to have your completion-handler block assign to a local variable, but your method in which you declared the local variable will probably have returned by the time block runs, so it won't be able to work with the value that the block <del>left</del> will leave in the variable.

Whatever you do with `pathToFile` should be either in the block itself, or in a method (taking an `NSURL *` argument) that the block can call.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that it doesn't follow the laws of scope.

Comment: Scope alone cannot work because, as I said, the block will run long after the method or function it's created in has finished running. Thus, that outer scope is no longer valid when the block runs. You can use `__block` when the function or method calls the block itself, but when it passes the block off to be queued and run later, that won't work, because the function or method will have finished already by the time the block goes to assign to the variable.

Comment: This is beyond frustrating. I'm essentially barred from doing anything else until I'm done with my URL, willingly or not. So, tasks like fetching a URL and then clicking a button to use it are impossible. Why, Apple, why?

Comment: You are not. Think asynchronously. Handle the URL in the block, or in a method that you call from the block. Don't stand around waiting for the URL to arrive; that's what the run loop is for. All you have to do, after running the panel, is return.

Answer (score 1):

you can also runModal after you begin the sheet you just need to make sure you end the sheet later. This way you don't have to bend to apple's will, it isn't deprecated and it should still work perfectly.

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openPanel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:nil];
NSInteger result = [openPanel runModal];
NSURL *url = nil;
if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) 
{
    url = [openPanel URL];
}
[NSApp endSheet:openPanel];
```

It seems a little bit like black magic coding but it does work.